# Difference between "I did say that" and "I said that"

Tags: meaning, informal-language

What is the difference between these two sentences:

> " Yes, guys, I **did say** that."
>
> “Yes, guys, I **said** that."

Comment: While the did places stress on the fact that it was indeed said, it also puts stress on the fact that this lies in the past.  "so you said [inexplicable thing]? " - "Yes guys, I did say that" [... but that's in the past, i now think...]   -------- Could you add context to the sentence? what went before, what came after?

Comment: it is related to youtube video when the creator of a video once said one thing and after that in the comment sections a lot of people start asking why fist he said He is bearish on ethereum and in the next video he said he is bullish on ethereum , basically two opposite things. and he comment on that with " Yes I did say that"

Comment: @ THEGreatGatsby - then my intuition about the stress on the past-ness of the utterance would seem to be correct : Yes guys, i DID say that, [but now i would take another approach].

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that 'did say' adds emphasis or confirmation, for example if the 'guys' had expressed doubt or surprise that you said that, or you had not been sure whether you had said it. Further emphasis could be provided by preceding 'did' with an adverb such as really, actually or definitely.